# Import a point in geoJson format into mapbox map with different coordinate system

Tags: javascript, geojson, coordinate-systems, mapbox, coordinate-transformation

I'm using the [mapbox.js API](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/) for building some kind of spatial-data-viewer.
In my (spatial) MySQL database, I have a table with 'geometry' elements in it (POINTS). These geometry elements are defined in the Lambert 72 coordinate system (EPSG:31370).
My (mapbox) map has the default wgs84 coordinate system.

I succeeded into importing my data from the db into a mapbox-geojson layer (using AJAX with JQuery) with [this mysql-to-geojson php script](https://github.com/bmcbride/PHP-Database-GeoJSON) based on geoPHP.

However, the elements still have the coordinates of the lambert72 system, so markers won't be positioned correctly. I know I could use a script to transform these coordinates, but **isn't there a 'cleaner' way to get the correct geoJson data (in wgs84 system, instead of lambert72) into my map?**

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [proj4leaflet](https://github.com/kartena/Proj4Leaflet) to reproject your lambert72 coordinates to WGS84.